# How can i keep the objects on mouse cursor after zoom in canvas - html5

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, kineticjs

I am trying to create a panel snap-to-grid objects in HTML5  but,
I have an error after the zoom is applies: I can not keep the object on the mouse cursor when it dragged , why ?

[You can see it as the following JSFiddle illustrates:](http://jsfiddle.net/wgpalumbo/F542m/)

The main function that control the current behavior are as follows:

```
hbox.on('dragmove', function(e) {
    var offsetX = e.offsetX || e.layerX,
    offsetY = e.offsetY || e.layerY;
    cellX = Math.floor(offsetX/CELL_SIZE)*CELL_SIZE-CELL_SIZE/2+3;
    cellY = Math.floor(offsetY/CELL_SIZE)*CELL_SIZE-CELL_SIZE/2+.5;
    hbox.setX(cellX);
    hbox.setY(cellY);
});
```

Huge thanks in advance to anyone who can help.

Comment: The mouse coordinates are reported in unscaled space. Therefore, you must adjust the reported mouseX and mouseY by the scaling factor.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I already done it and not works

Comment: I looked at your fiddle and your "position mouse" coordinates are still off by exactly the amount of the scaling factor.  For example, if you move your mouse to the top-left of your grid and then scale the grid and then move your mouse back to the top-left of your grid. You must fix your code so that those top-left x/y are the same both before and after the scaling.

Comment: Thanks Again, I understood, however I am struggling to find the factor, could you please help me...